# How to load https web site with proxy in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, http-proxy

I am using chrome and selenium in python. I have a code for using proxy in chrome it work but only for http web site (I think) and it doesn't load https(ssl).

I tried this code

```
from selenium import webdriver
http_proxy = "http://118.69.134.2:80"
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={http_proxy}')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://httpbin.org/ip")
print(driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "body").text)
driver.quit()
```

It fails with `ERR_TIMED_OUT`

Comment: first you need to find working proxy server. Many free proxy servers don't send HTTPS or even don't work at all. And this can be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try to add extensions to webdriver to achieve the purpose of using the proxy, provided that your proxy is working properly, please check: [gist](https://gist.github.com/equinoxel/151655b26f2ae90655e494eb5873a025)

Comment: Yes, it's true, my proxy had a problem to forward https